# Right place to add a common function which updates UI component in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on AngularJS applicaion. UI is divided into two parts. On the left side, I have a navigation tree panel. If user clicks on any of the item in the tree, we load the corresponding page on the right hand side. On some of the pages (load of the right side panel), we have provided some button, which loads a page and update the navigation tree panel.

Currently, I have copied the logic at multiple places which updates the navigation tree. I wonder which the right place to put this logic?

I am thinking of using something like this:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

 MyNamespace.helpers = {
   isNotString: function(str) {
     return (typeof str !== "string");
   }
 };
```

in controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []).                                                                                                                                                                                  
  controller('dataCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.helpers = MyNamespace.helpers;
  });
```

or may be add the function to root scope:

```
$rootScope.isNotString = function(str) {
   return (typeof str !== "string");
  }
```

Comment: Seems more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NewDev the question in this scope seems very "boiled down" to me and might get closed as "hypothetical code" on codereview.se for more information, please refer to the [Guide to Code Review for StackOverflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777)

Comment: @Vogel612, sure.. I don't disagree...